# Display Error Text under Dropdown Button Input Box

Tags: flutter

I am new to Flutter and I am creating a form with TextFormfield and DropdownButtonFormField. I am trying to display the error message of the DropdownButtonFormField(Site Crop) to **below the text box** like how the site name field display its error message.
Should I continue using DropdownButtonFormField or is there a better way to do this?
[FormSample](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5mcCl.png)

**code for dropdown**

```
child: DropdownButtonHideUnderline(
        child: DropdownButtonFormField(
          decoration: InputDecoration(
            errorBorder: InputBorder.none,
            enabledBorder: UnderlineInputBorder(
              borderSide: BorderSide(color: Colors.white),
            ),
          ),
          hint: Text(
            'Choose Country',
            style: TextStyle(
              fontSize: 16,
              color: NewSite.black.withOpacity(0.6),
            ),
          ),
          validator: (value) => value == null
              ? 'Please fill in' : null,
          value: _selectedLocation,
          onChanged: (newValue) {
            setState(() {
              _selectedLocation = newValue;
            });
          },
          items: _locations.map((location) {
            return DropdownMenuItem(
              child: new Text(location),
              value: location,
            );
          }).toList(),
          icon: Icon(Icons.arrow_drop_down, color: ColorTheme.main,),
          style: TextStyle(color: NewSite.black),
          isExpanded: true,
          elevation: 26,
          dropdownColor: NewSite.white,

        ),
      ),
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try **Form** Widget,
Wrap this your filed inside Form,

like this

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

class DemoDropDownCreate extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _DemoDropDownCreate createState() =>
      _DemoDropDownCreate();
}

class _DemoDropDownCreate
    extends State<DemoDropDownCreate> {
  final _formKey = GlobalKey<FormState>();
  bool _autovalidate = false;
  String selectedCountry;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: Form(
        key: _formKey,
        autovalidate: _autovalidate,
        child:
        Column(
          children: <Widget>[
            DropdownButtonFormField<String>(
              value: selectedCountry,
              hint: Text(
                'Select Country',
              ),
              onChanged: (salutation) =>
                  setState(() => selectedCountry = salutation),
              validator: (value) =>  value.isEmpty ? 'field required' : null,
              items:
              ['India', 'Japan'].map<DropdownMenuItem<String>>((String value) {
                return DropdownMenuItem<String>(
                  value: value,
                  child: Text(value),
                );
              }).toList(),
            ),
            FlatButton(
              child: Text('PROCEED'),
              color: Colors.green,
              onPressed: () {
                if (_formKey.currentState.validate()) {
                  //form is valid, proceed further
                  _formKey.currentState.save();//save once fields are valid, onSaved method invoked for every form fields
                  print("success");
                } else {
                  setState(() {
                    _autovalidate = true; //enable realtime validation
                  });
                  print("Please select all field");

                }
              },
            )
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: Yes, this can display the error message below the textbox but it seems like I could not add borders to the textbox to make it the same as the same style in the picture I attached.

Answer (score 3):

You can indeed use validators for `DropdownButtonFormField`

```
 DropdownButtonFormField(
    validator: (dynamic value) => value.isEmpty ? "An error happened or please pick something" : null,
    decoration: InputDecoration(....
```

you can change `value.isEmpty` to any condition you want, same as the `"An error happened"` message.